# how to implement logout process in JSF application

Tags: jsf

how to implement logout process in JSF application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```java
public String logout() {
    ((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
         .getSession()).invalidate();
     return "homePage";
}
```

and

```
<h:commandLink value="#{msg.logout}" action="#{logoutBean.logout}" />
```

Comment: thank u Bozho. 1 question will my faces session map objects i.e. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()  will also be invalidated?

Comment: @Bozho Is there a standard way to set the msg.logout variable when a user logs in when using j_security_check?

Comment: How about this one? `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession()`