# why jsf command doesn't work in js?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have some code, and I don't know why he nor work, when I want call `logoutAction()` managed bean function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const sessionTimeOut = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};
    function startTimer(timeoutCount = 0) {
      if (#{request.userPrincipal != null}) {
        if (timeoutCount >= sessionTimeOut) {
            logoutAction();
        }
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000, timeoutCount + 1);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

and my form

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="logoutAction" actionListener="#{logoutBean.logoutProcess}"/>
  </h:form>
```

Help me please.

Comment: I don't know JSF at all, but are you not mixing front-end and back-end code? Like, expecting JS in the browser to launch a function that exists on the server?

Comment: If you like to logout a jsf session. Listen to BalusC himself. See the light:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619827/how-to-invalidate-session-in-jsf-2-0 and this is also a good example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499317/how-to-implement-logout-process-in-jsf-application if you want it in javascript. Please explain why it is needed first

Comment: `#{request.userPrincipal != null}` is only evaluated when your page is rendered, not each time your timer fires.